# Finding the creator of the stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am with an organization where people can create stored procedure for the same schema.

Is there a way I can find out who created the stored procedures?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't let people use shared credentials. Have them use personal credentials with proxy access to the shared schema, and audit all DDL (create/alter/drop) commands. If you aren't using proxy access and aren't auditing DDL then there isn't any way to know for sure who did what.

Comment: How are people creating stored procedures in the same schema?  Is everyone logging in to the shared schema account?  Are they logging in to their own personal account with `create any procedure` privileges?  Are you using proxy authentication?  What sort of auditing do you have enabled?